# XSLT to bind data with view in ms xslt works, but errors in saxon

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, saxon

This is a simple example of something I'm trying to do. I can get something to work in MS XSLT (using visual studio).

The idea is to take a "view" which is an XML that defines how a layout should look.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rows>
  <row>
    <column value="name"/>
    <column value="id"/>
  </row>
</rows>
```

the XSLT should take a layout view and copy everything to the output except foreach "row" it should create a row in the output table, and interpret the columns based on the value.

so if we take some data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<customers>
  <customer id="123" name="Mr Bloggs"/>
  <customer id="124" name="Mrs Smith"/>
</customers>
```

we would expect the output to look something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rows>
  <row>
    <column value="Mrs Smith"/>
    <column value="124"/>
  </row>
  <row>
    <column value="Mr Bloggs"/>
    <column value="123"/>
  </row>
</rows>
```

i.e. the cross product of the data rows and the view columns to build a table.
Everything else should be copied, the view may contain all sorts of things that the XSLT need not understand, it should just blindly copy them through.

So my prototype in MS XSLT is this (which works, but for me seems quite clunky).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="customers" select="/customers/customer"/>

  <xsl:template match="/customers" priority="1">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="document('View.xml')"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row" priority="1">
    <xsl:variable name="this" select="."/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$customers">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$this" mode="processRow">
        <xsl:with-param name="customer" select="."/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="column" mode="processRow">
    <xsl:param name="customer"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@value = 'name'">
          <xsl:value-of select="$customer/@name"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="@value = 'id'">
          <xsl:value-of select="$customer/@id"/>
        </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="processRow">
    <xsl:param name="customer"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"  mode="processRow">
        <xsl:with-param name="customer" select="$customer"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the intention is to capture the data (i.e. customers) in a global variable, then open and process the view, using something a bit like the identity transform, but intercept the "row" to "inject" the data, 1 row per item, and intercept the column to interpret the view based on the currently processed item. Everything else is just copied across, whilst passing through the customer about to be processed.

If I run this via Saxon9ee-api (C#) it blows up with

```
Error on line 7 of file:///C:/Kookeralla/.....:
  XPDY0002: The context item for axis step root/customers is absent
  In template rule with match="row" on line 13 of file:///C:/Kookeralla/.....
     invoked by xsl:apply-templates at file:///C:/Kookeralla/....../#47
  In template rule with match="(((element() | text()) | comment()) | processing-instruction())" on line 45 of file:///C:/Kookeralla/......
     invoked by built-in template rule (text-only)
  In template rule with match="document-node()/element(Q{}customers)" on line 9 of file:///C:/Kookeralla/.....
     invoked by xsl:apply-templates at file:///C:/Kookeralla/..../Debug/#10
  In template rule with match="document-node()/element(Q{}customers)" on line 9 of file:///C:/Kookeralla/....../Debug/
     invoked by built-in template rule (text-only)
```

which I don't massively understand (for the moment I want to keep it in XSLT 1.0).

---

Edit to include C# code, this code works with the identity transform

```
        var xslt = "BindModelToView.xslt";
        //var xslt = "identity.xslt";
        var data = "SimpleModel.xml";
        var baseDir = new Uri(new Uri("file://"), AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);

        var xslt2 = new Uri(baseDir, xslt);
        Processor processor = new Processor(true);
        var compiler = processor.NewXsltCompiler();
        compiler.BaseUri = baseDir;
        compiler.GetUnderlyingCompilerInfo().setJustInTimeCompilation(false);
        var compile = compiler.Compile(xslt2);

        //Processor processor = new Processor(true);
        Serializer serializer = processor.NewSerializer();
        var output = new StringWriter();
        //serializer.SetOutputWriter(Console.Out);
        serializer.SetOutputWriter(output);
        var transformer = compile.Load30();
        // Transform the source XML and serialize the result document
        transformer.SchemaValidationMode = SchemaValidationMode.None;
        transformer.ApplyTemplates(File.OpenRead(data), serializer);
        return output.ToString();
```

this code reports this

```
Error at char 1 in xsl:variable/@select on line 7 column 64 of BindModelToView.xslt:
  XPDY0002: The context item for axis step root/customers is absent
  In template rule with match="row" on line 13 of BindModelToView.xslt
     Focus
        Context item: /rows/row[1]
        Context position: 2
     Local variables
        $this = <row>
     invoked by xsl:apply-templates at file:///C:/Kookeralla/SaxonEEExample/ValidateXslt/bin/Debug/BindModelToView.xslt#47
  In template rule with match="( element() | text() | comment() | processing-instruction() )" on line 45 of BindModelToView.xslt
     invoked by built-in template rule (text-only)
  In template rule with match="document-node()/element(Q{}customers)" on line 9 of BindModelToView.xslt
     invoked by xsl:apply-templates at file:///C:/Kookeralla/SaxonEEExample/ValidateXslt/bin/Debug/BindModelToView.xslt#10
  In template rule with match="document-node()/element(Q{}customers)" on line 9 of BindModelToView.xslt
     invoked by built-in template rule (text-only)
```

Comment: Show your C# code running the transformation

Comment: its a slightly convoluted setup, I'll have to create a bespoke function to show the basics, give me 10 mins or so

Comment: is it when the "view.xml" has the "apply-templates" invoked? This is the first time I've used document(), and I don't apply templates very often either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the use of a global variable trying to select the input document while only calling `ApplyTemplates` but not setting `GlobalContextItem`. It might be easier in this case to call `transformer.Transform(File.OpenRead(data), serializer);` in this case.

Comment: tbh I pretty much hate setting a global var to some subset of the source doc, then flipping the context using document()...is there a cleaner way to do it in the XSLT?

Comment: @MrDatKookerellaLtd, I tried to explain and solve the problem with the API use of Saxon's `Xslt30Transformer` with this answer, any global `xsl:variable` or `xsl:param` trying to select the initial match selection will run into this problem, whether you use `document()` somewhere or not. So for your use of the global param you would need to use the `Transform` method in my understanding of the API or build the input XdmNode yourself and set GlobalContextItem, which might get complicated in the case of schema-aware XSLT and validation.

Comment: Basically, if you want to replicate the way that an XSLT 1.0 processor behaves, it's simplest to use the Transform method (this sets the global context item to the node that the initial ApplyTemplates applies to). As you say, it's really better to avoid using global variables bound to your source document (it makes it harder to reuse your code as part of a pipeline). The XSLT 2.0+ way of doing this would be to bind $customers to a tunnel parameter;